# Deezer suggestions API

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sdk, deezer

In Android SDK there is a player state `PLAYER_COMPLETED`. Is there a similare state in iOS and Javascript SDK?

Because I have problem with finding out the end of the song, PLAYER_COMPLETED is awesome but it only exists in Android.

My second problem is suggestions. Will there be any API to provide suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we plan to add a PLAYER_COMPLETED event at least to the Javascript SDK, though I can't provide a specific timeframe for that now.

Regarding suggestions, we released it last week: http://developers.deezer.com/api/search/autocomplete